# I get "Can't find any GWT Modules on this page"

Tags: gwt

I am trying to set up my eclipse with gwt and after I installed Jdk 8 and eclipse 2019-06 and gwt eclipse plugin 3.0 I created the sample project with code generated and when I try to run the sample code in GWT Development mode it gives me url http://localhost:9876 and when I open it I get "Can't find any GWT Modules on this page" Can you please help why It is giving me Can't find any GWT Modules on this page. I am assuming if I am running it in development mode I don't need to set up web server so I didn't. I didn't used gwt for long time and I am lost why it is giving me this can't find gwt module message when I load the page. Can you please help?

Comment: Please add the code snippet that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

You still need a server, if you want to run any java code on your server. Such as code for talking to your database.

Gwt only does 2 things:

1: is is handling the client side, where it generate javascript from your java code.

2: It includes a .jar file, which can be used together with a java servlet server such as apache tomcat to serialize java objects which can then be send between the client and the server. And this .jar file will serialize all needed objects. And gwt will generate the needed javascript code.

Gwt does not itself include any http server. The address http://localhost:9876 is only used to configure gwt. It is just a page with 2 buttons to turn dev mode on/off.

The eclipse plugin does include a embeded webserver which can be used for gwt development. I have newer done this and I think that installing an independent java tomcat server is the best solution.

But if you want to use the eclipse embeded webserver you need the "Run in development mode with Jetty." - Jetty is the name of the embeded java servlet server.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will add the tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the plugin from Google ?

If so, this is outdated. I advice you to use the plugin from branflake. You can find this plugin on GitHub : https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin

Also on that GitHub page a lot of documentation is available. Like a link to a very helpfull YouTube playlist: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DU7ZQVLR5Zo&list=PLBbgqtDgdc_TqzA-qXrjgTFMC_6DKAQyT

My advice is to watch these YouTube videos to get you started. If you follow them all should be working without a problem.

I haven't used this plugin for a while since I switched to IntelliJ. But I did use it in GWT2.8.2 so it should still work fine.